# Android: setOnRefreshListener is called even if I tap on the outside of my ListView

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I have this layout base:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_list_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
            android:background="@color/background" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

During this fragment creation, I add a specific list:

```
 <ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1px" />
```

So when I tap on the area (outside the list view) in red, the listener is called:

```
mSwipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        ...
    }
});
```

[image]

So, why this listener is called, and can I avoid that behavior?

Comment: Change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` or in SwipeRefreshLayout use `wrap_content` for height

Comment: SwipeRefresh is set to matchcontent, so that red area is part of it

Comment: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: I've updated my XML with wrap_content (see above). The result is the same.

Comment: change the height of relative layout, to wrap to.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_list_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <ListView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:divider="@color/list_divider"
android:dividerHeight="1px" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
            android:background="@color/background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

use this 
you was implement swipe to refresh on whole fragment including listView.

Comment: I don't understand your post ?